# Updating existing dictionary key:tuple with new tuple (dict object not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I've reached an error telling me my dictionary object is not callable and I want to make sure I referencing everything correctly before I contact the API developer. Currently coding for Opentrons OT2 robot.

My project is to correlate a volume in a tube with a value that tells the robot what height to set. The dictionary (dict_15ml_50ml) is written in the format that the API developer recommends.
The code follows this pattern:
volume set> add or subtract volume> round volume> reference volume to vol_15ml_starstedt> create tuple with adjusted volume and new height>replace old tuple in dict_15ml_50ml with new tuple.

When I run this in jupyter, I get the error saying that the dict object is not callable.

```html
import opentrons
from opentrons import protocol_api
from opentrons.simulate import get_protocol_api
import math
from datetime import datetime
from math import floor

protocol = get_protocol_api('2.8')
tuberack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_15_tuberack_nest_15ml_conical','2','tuberack')
tiprack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_96_tiprack_300ul','4')
instrument = protocol.load_instrument('p300_single', 'left')
instrument.home

vol_15ml_starstedt= {14000: 104, 13500: 101, 13000: 98, 12500: 94, 12000: 91, 11500: 88, 11000: 85, 10500: 81,
                    }
dict_15ml_50ml={
tuberack['A1']:(15000,95), tuberack['A2']:(15000,95),
                }

dict_tuberack= dict_15ml_50ml

def get_volume(dict_labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
    return tup[0]

def get_height(dict_labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
    return tup[1]

def volume_add(volume,dict_labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
    volume1 = tup[0]
    volume2 = volume
    adj_volume = volume1+volume2
    adj_list=list(tup)
    adj_list[0]=(adj_volume)
    tup=tuple(adj_list)
    return tup[0]

def volume_sub(volume,dict_labware,well):
    tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
    volume1 = tup[0]
    volume2 = volume
    adj_volume = volume1-volume2
    adj_list=list(tup)
    adj_list[0]=(adj_volume)
    tup=tuple(adj_list)
    return tup[0]

def tup_update(volume,dict_vol,dict_labware,well):
    
    tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
    adj_list=list(tup)
    adj_list[0]=volume
    divisor=1
    if volume >=1000:
        divisor=1000
    elif volume <1000 >= 100:
        divisor=100
    else:
        divisor = 10
    
    def round_down(volume,divisor):
        vol_even=floor(volume/divisor)*divisor
        return vol_even
    
    vol_even=round_down(volume,divisor)
    new_height=dict_vol.get(vol_even)
    adj_list[1]=new_height
    
    new_tup=tuple(adj_list)
    target=dict_labware(tuberack[well])
    target.update(new_tup)




x=volume_sub(2000,dict_tuberack,'A1')
tup_update(x,vol_15ml_starstedt,dict_tuberack,'A1')
print(dict_tuberack(tuberack['A1']))
```

Comment: `dict_labware(tuberack[well])` and the other similar instance are treating the dictionary as a function. Did you mean `dict_labware[tuberack[well]]`, or `dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate the key has to be referenced as tuberack['A1'] because tuberack is a function that talks to the robot.

Comment: You're referencing the key of `tuberack` correctly. The problem is with how you're referencing the key of `dict_labware`. It should be `[]`, not `()`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok, so I fixed that reference under def tup_update. Now it tells me that the tuple object has no attribute update

Comment: @Barmar you're correct on that, and it fixed the current error. Now it tells me that the tuple object has no attribute update

Comment: Tuples are immutable. What you probably want is `dict_labware[tuberack[well]] = new_tup`

Comment: @barmar You nailed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    target=dict_labware(tuberack[well])
    target.update(new_tup)
```

should be

```
    dict_labware[tuberack[well]] = new_tup
```

You use `[]` to refer to elements of a dictionary. `()` is for calling functions. `update()` is for merging dictionaries, but `target` and `new_tup` are tuples, not dictionaries. Tuples are immutable so you can't merge them like that.

Answer (score 0):

@barmar and @carcigenicate got the answer.

def tup update was changed to

```
def tup_update(volume,dict_vol,dict_labware,well):

tup = dict_labware.get(tuberack[well])
adj_list=list(tup)
adj_list[0]=volume
divisor=1
if volume >=1000:
    divisor=1000
elif volume <1000 >= 100:
    divisor=100
else:
    divisor = 10

def round_down(volume,divisor):
    vol_even=floor(volume/divisor)*divisor
    return vol_even

vol_even=round_down(volume,divisor)
new_height=dict_vol.get(vol_even)
adj_list[1]=new_height

*new_tup=tuple(adj_list)
dict_labware[tuberack[well]]=new_tup*
```